# Generate Julian date

Tags: php, date, julian-date

I have a piece of code which generates Julian date, but i need to generate a three digit Julian date. Can any help me out

Code:

```
$jd = GregorianToJD(08, 02, 2013);
```

Output:  **2456507**

Comment: that mean array of year day,...?

Comment: Do you mean the day of the year? If so, that's not a [Julian date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_date).

Comment: i really dont know, but i have requirement where they have been asking for three digit julian date, might only be day ?

Answer (score 0):

see this function **cal_from_jd** return tree of calendar information like month, day, year, day of week
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-from-jd.php

```
  $jd = GregorianToJD(08, 02, 2013);
  print_r(cal_from_jd($jd, CAL_JULIAN));
```

if you have php 5.3 and newer version you can use **IntlDateFormatter** that can convert To all calender and timezone
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php